# What's real about SO_REUSEADDR

Tags: tcp

In man page about **SO_REUSEADDR**(man 7 socket):

> When the listening socket is bound to INADDR_ANY with a specific port then  it  is  not  possible  to  bind to this port for any local address.  Argument is an integer boolean flag.

But in Unix Network Programming, I find:

> SO_REUSEADDR allows a new server to be started on the same port as an existing server that is bound to the wildcard address, as long as each instance binds a different local IP address. This is common for a site hosting multiple HTTP servers using the IP alias technique (Section A.4). Assume the local host's primary IP address is 198.69.10.2 but it has two aliases: 198.69.10.128 and 198.69.10.129. Three HTTP servers are started. The first HTTP server would call bind with the wildcard as the local IP address and a local port of 80 (the well-known port for HTTP). The second server would call bind with a local IP address of 198.69.10.128 and a local port of 80. But, this second call to bind fails unless SO_REUSEADDR is set before the call. The third server would bind 198.69.10.129 and port 80. Again, SO_REUSEADDR is required for this final call to succeed.

Aren't they contradictory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not in conflict. The second quote provides a way around the default behaviour specified by the first paragraph.

Comment: Thanks! In tcp, is it right to say this: local ip and INADDR_ANY(same port) are considered as conflict address and bind will fail no matter SO_REUSEADDR is set or not? Can you give me the discussion link? Maybe more detail information can be seen.